# change directory, subdirectory, folder and file permissions in ubuntu GUI

Tags: permissions, directory

I am having problems installing, upgrading and deleting Wordpress plugins on my VM-Virtual Box LAMP server.

I have read that the issue has something to do with permissions that are assigned in my 
var/www/wp-content folder.

I am a windows user and rather new to ubuntu terminal. I am finding that so many so called "experts" here provide all sorts of code in order to fix this problem in the terminal, however, when i follow those commands in the terminal i seem to do more harm than good to my ubuntu instillation and the wordpress problem is not being resolved (and it also seems a lot of others encounter similar issues).

**Question**

how i can **bulk** change directory, folder and file permissions in Ubuntu using the GUI. (It can be done quite easily in windows GUI surely Ubuntu has a similar option)

Answer (score 3):

> how i can bulk change directory, folder and file permissions in Ubuntu using the GUI.

What you want to do is a admin task so you need nautilus in administration mode. From a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or dash, "terminal") issue:

```
sudo nautilus
```

- enter password;
- navigate to directory
- Right click on empty space in the main window of nautilus
- Click on properties and go to tab permissions
- Change permissons to what you need

Example of a random directory from my system (/var/tmp/):

[image]

The highlighted part does the files inside the directory.

2 comments:

- Linux is multi user so we need to do this in a different way than Windows does. Our method has to also take into account that there are more than 1 user on the system (and in single user mode there is still you as user and you as administrator).
- Do not forget to exit Nautilus. Using it as administrator can destroy your system.

Comment: yes i tried that, however, in release 12.04 i noticed that the permissions for sub folders and files is not changing. Is this broken??? In release 13.10 it seems to work differently to what i expected. In either case, it doesnt alter the permissions on sub directories folders and files. Is there no need in linux...does the permission set in the top level override the permissions in sub directories?